# Glyphicon not showing inside button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, glyphicons

I have added a button with a glyphicon inside it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="false"></span> Star
</button>
```

I see the button but don't see the glyphicon inside it. Maybe my font files aren't in the right spot, I also might have updated bootstrap but not the font files (would that cause the glyphs not to show up?). I haven't really touched the folder structure or the font files that were included in the project when I created it in VS.

Here is my folder structure for the bootstrap and font files. It is basically the default structure that Visual Studio set up for the ASP.Net MVC project type.
Question - if this isn't the correct folder structure to access the font files then why was it created like this by default?

[image]

Comment: The default path is `../fonts/` relative to the bootstrap CSS file. So your folder structure looks fine. If you say: "I also might have updated bootstrap but not the font files". Does that mean you made a customized download and unchecked glyphicons?

Comment: no, it means that I might have downloaded some later version (later then the one included with the VS project) of bootstrap and added the bootstrap.js files and possibly the .css files without updating the font files.

Comment: I am getting intellisense for the glyphicon css when I type it into the class! so it looks like it recognizes it on some level,the glyph just isn't showing in the button like it should. I'm just wondering if I should update all boostrap files to the latest to see if that helps?

Comment: Look for the '@font-face' rule in your bootstrap.css to make sure the path is right. Then inspect your site with any developer tool (e.g. ctrl+shift+i in Chrome). Does the font file gets loaded, Is the CSS applied to the element, ...?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="false"></span> Star
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My @font-face paths looked like this.

> url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");

but my folder with my font files was in

../fonts/files

so I added a bootstrap folder and now it works. Not sure why it's probably because I updated some of the bootstrap files without updating the font files.